# Como convertir un elemento HTML a string en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string

accedo a un elemento de mi pagina y lo guardo en una variable:

```
var nodo = document.getElementsByClassName('prueba');
```

si hago un

```
var nodo = String(nodo);
```

no me funciona, se que es un array de objetos pero si lo paso a string solo me sale un texto que es `[object HTMLCollection]` y no hay manera. 
La cuestión es que intento guardar todo el HTML de ese nodo en una variable del tipo String pero no hay manera.

Alguien se le ocurre como lo puedo hacer?

ACTUALIZADO:

Gracias a todos los que me habéis dedicado vuestro tiempo a ayudarme, espero poder devolver el favor, la manera fácil ha sido:

```
var nodo = document.getElementsByClassName('ep-gadget epgadget-externalvideo')[0].outerHTML
```

se me ocurrió que existiría esta función al ver el inspector de elementos la opción copy outerHTML

Comment: ese elemento con clase `prueba` que es? `<p>`? `<button>`?

Comment: haz un console.log, cuando utilizas **document.getElementsByClassName** te devuelve un arreglo por lo tanto debes hacer nodo[0]

Comment: No está clara tu pregunta, ¿Quieres obtener el HTML de un elemento como cadena `<div class="example">First div element with class="example".</div>` y almacenarlo en una variable?. Recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/51540/edit).

Comment: Sí, quiero guardar todo el HTML de ese nodo en una variable del tipo string para luego hacer unas modificaciones, el problema es que no consigo cambiarlo a String por mucho que lo intente. Aprovecho la ocasión para dar las gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: @brunocelaya eso que dijiste en la actualizacion fue lo que te puse yo en la respuesta ...

Comment: @brunocelaya como dices: "espero poder devolver el favor," puedes marcar una respuesta como aceptada. Y en la pregunta no deberias añadir la solucion . Por favor, editala.

Comment: @brunocelaya: Aunque se menciona en el comentario previo, como pasan las semanas y no hay cambio te lo comento de nuevo, en la pregunta sólo debe incluirse información de la misma, si deseas publicar una solución, hazlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 11):

Puedes iterar sobre la respuesta de tu `getElementByClassName` haciendo:

```js
var list= document.getElementsByClassName("minodo"),
    array_de_strings = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    console.log(list[i].textContent);
    array_de_strings.push(list[i].textContent);
}
console.log(array_de_strings.join(', '));
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="minodo">primero</li>
<li class="minodo">segundo</li>
<li class="minodo">tercero</li>
<li class="minodo">cuarto</li>
</ul>
```

Ojo, La salida de un `getElementByClassName` es un <strike>**nodeList**</strike>, el cual es iterable y sin embargo **no es un array** por lo cual no puedes simplemente hacer un map o reduce para concatenarlo. Por eso apliqué la técnica burda de ir añadiéndole los elementos a un array vacío. Esto último es sólo una manera más de operar con la salida de un nodeList.

## Update 2020

**Fe de Erratas**

Primero: getElementsByClassName no devuelve un [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) sino un [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Perdonen por no haber verificado esa noción durante tres años.

**Usar selectores CSS3**

Con la compatibilidad universal y casi-casi homogénea de los selectores CSS3, es más cómodo usar `document.querySelectorAll` (este sí devuelve un NodeList, lo prometo). en vez de `document.getElementsByClassName`. En vez de un método específico para clases, puedes usarlo en reemplazo de `getElementsByTagname` y `getElementsByName`, con la desventaja de que es menos eficiente si el DOM es muy complejo.

Por otro lado resulta inmediato a la vista el tipo de propiedad que buscas, dado que la búsqueda por id usa un char '#id_elemento' y por clase se usa un punto '.nombre_clase'.

Replicando el ejemplo original, pero reemplazando el bucle `for` con algo más conciso:

```
var list= document.querySelectorAll(".minodo"),
    array_de_strings= Array.from(list)
                      .map(element=>element.textContent);
```

Como `list` no es un Array lo sano es convertirlo en tal usando Array.from(...). (Pero el ejemplo subsiguiente es mejor)

```js
var list= document.querySelectorAll(".minodo"),
    array_de_strings= Array.from(list)
                      .map(element=>element.textContent);
console.log(array_de_strings.join(', '));
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="minodo">primero</li>
<li class="minodo">segundo</li>
<li class="minodo">tercero</li>
<li class="minodo">cuarto</li>
</ul>
```

**Usar CSS3 + destructuring**

La destructuración y el spread operator de la especificación ES2015 es todavía más bonita

```js
var list= document.querySelectorAll(".minodo"),
    array_de_strings= [...list]
                      .map(element=>element.textContent);
console.log(array_de_strings.join(', '));
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="minodo">primero</li>
<li class="minodo">segundo</li>
<li class="minodo">tercero</li>
<li class="minodo">cuarto</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

Es lo mismo que ocurre si haces lo siguiente:

```
var prueba = {a: 1, b: 2};
console.log(String(prueba));

// [object Object]
```

Si quisieras una representación de ese objeto en forma de `String` deberías utilizar `JSON.stringify`:

```
var prueba = {a: 1, b: 2};
console.log(JSON.stringify(prueba));

// {"a":1,"b":2}
```

Lo mismo ocurre con otros tipos de objeto. Al utilizar el método `getElementsByClassName` te devuelve un objeto `HTMLCollection` (contiene todos los elementos en tu documento que tienen esa clase), por lo tanto si intentas convertirlo a `String` obtendrás `[object HTMLCollection]`. Para devolver una representación `String` de un elemento `HTML` deberías usar los métodos `innerHTML` (para una representación `String` del contenido del elemento) o `outerHTML` para una representación `String` del elemento en sí mismo. Sólo debes tener en cuenta que estos métodos deben usarse en un objeto de tipo `Element`, por lo que si quieres hacerlo en un objeto de tipo `HTMLCollection` debes iterar en el mismo:

```js
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("prueba");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementos, function (el) {

    console.log(el.outerHTML);

});
```

```html
<div class="prueba">uno</div>
<div class="prueba">dos</div>
<div class="prueba">tres</div>
```

Aunque si tu código debe ser soportado como mínimo por `Internet Explorer 8`, para seleccionar un solo elemento por clase, en vez de usar `getElementsByClassName` podrías usar `querySelector`, que devuelve directamente un objeto de tipo `Element` en vez de un objeto tipo `HTMLCollection` ya que selecciona el primer elemento que coincida con el selector:

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector(".prueba");
console.log( elemento.outerHTML );
```

```html
<div class="no-prueba">uno</div>
<div class="prueba">dos</div>
<div class="no-prueba">tres</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

`getElementsByClassName` devuelve una colección de todos los elementos con esa clase. Intenta acceder al elemento que tu quieres y coger el texto.

ej:

```js
 var nodo = document.getElementsByClassName('prueba');
    console.log(nodo[0].textContent);  //accedo al primer elemento
```

```html
<p class="prueba">Hola!</p>
```

Tambien puedes sacar `nodeValue`, `outterHTML` o `innerHTML` ... en funcion de lo que necesites

Answer (score 4):

Hola que tal buenas tardes. Se que la duda está resuelta, pero si te es más cómodo o quieres conocer la alternativa vía Jquery, sería la siguiente para tomar el primer nodo del DOM (siguiendo el ejemplo de más arriba).

```
var auxVar = $('li').first().html(); //Toma el html del primer <li> de todos.
 console.log(auxVar);
 console.log(typeof auxVar); // Comprueba el tipo de variable. String
```

De ésta manera hacemos lo mismo. Yo intento usar Javascript más que Jquery pero muchas cosas para entender cómo funcionan, puede venir bien experimentar en Jquery (si tuvieras acceso naturalmente) y luego replicar el ejemplo en Javascript para comprenderlo.

Answer (score 2):

Es facil
Simplemente tienes que hacer esto

```
var nodo = document.getElementsByClassName('prueba');
console.log(nodo[0].innerHTML)
```